# Write XML in a string c#

Tags: c#, xml, string

I was wondering how I could , when  I get the xml write it in a string ?

Because when I do this :

```
{
     XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("MYURL");
     string textresult = xdoc.Root.ToString();
     Label_RequestResult.Text = textresult;
}
```

my Label_RequestResult.text will be equal to the value of the node of the XML.

I would like to actually return the whole xml structure .

Is this posible ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: No, it really won't - `XElement.ToString` returns the whole XML structure... please provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: `xdoc.Root.ToString()` should already output the complete XML structure, starting at the root. Please extend your question with (a) **your expected output** and (b) **your actual output**.

Comment: Yes it actually returns all the values in the output. But what I would like more than just the values is the <node> etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case `string textresult = xdoc.ToString();` did the job.
I got the whole structure, even with spaces and line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should something like this: have you tried already?

```
string textresult = xdoc.Root.Value();
```